# How to create an aggregate table (data mart) that will improve chart performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, aggregate, data-warehouse

I created a table named **user_preferences** where user preferences have been grouped by **user_id** and **month**.

**Table**:

[image]

Each month I collect all **user_ids** and assign all preferences:

- city
- district
- number of rooms
- the maximum price they can spend

The plan assumes displaying a graph showing users' shopping intentions like this:
[image]

The blue line is the number of interested users for the selected values in the filters.

The graph should enable filtering by parameters marked in red. 
What you see above is a simplified form for clarifying the subject. In fact, there are many more users. Every month, the table increases by several hundred thousand records. The SQL query retrieving data (feeding) for chart lasts up to 50 seconds. It's far too much - I can't afford it.

So, I need to create a table (table/aggregation/data mart) where I will be able to insert the previously calculated **numer of interested users** for all combinations. Thanks to this, the end user will not have to wait for the data to count.

Details below:

[image]

Now the question is - how to create such a table in **PostgreSQL**? 
I know how to write a SQL query that will calculate a specific example.

```
SELECT
 month,
 count(DISTINCT user_id) interested_users
FROM 
 user_preferences
WHERE
 month BETWEEN '2020-01' AND '2020-03'
 AND city = 'Madrid'
 AND district = 'Latina'
 AND rooms IN (1,2)
 AND price_max BETWEEN 400001 AND 500000
GROUP BY 
 1
```

The question is - how to calculate all possible combinations? Can I write multiple nested loop in SQL?

The topic is extremely important to me, I think it will also be useful to others for the future.
I will be extremely grateful for any tips.

Comment: Can you show your current query?

Comment: Yes, example query in SQL for feeding chart added to description

Comment: Why you are counting the `DISTINCT` users? Is this important?

Comment: I want to know how many people are interested in a given type of property. One customer may be interested in several types in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, base on your query, you have the following filters:

- month
- city
- distirct
- rooms
- price_max

You can try creating a view with the following structure:

```
SELECT month
     ,city
     ,distirct
     ,rooms
     ,price_max
     ,count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM  user_preferences
GROUP BY month
        ,city
        ,distirct
        ,rooms
        ,price_max
```

You can make this view [materialized](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html). So, the query behind the view will not be executed when queried. It will behave like table.

When you are adding new records to the base table you will need to refresh the view (unfortunately, posgresql does not support auto-refresh like others):

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view;
```

or you can scheduled a task.

If you are using only exact search for each field, this will work. But in your example, you have criteria like:

```
month BETWEEN '2020-01' AND '2020-03'
AND rooms IN (1,2)
AND price_max BETWEEN 400001 AND 500000
```

In such cases, I usually write the same query but `SUM` the data from the materialized view. In your case, you are using `DISTINCT` and this may lead to `counting` a user multiple times.

If this is a issue, you need to precalculate too many combinations and I doubt this is the answer. Alternatively, you can try to normalize your data - this will improve the performance of the aggregations.